# Best approach to accomplish

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have following list in which i have applied different filter according to the some business rules and some functions .Every thing is working fine . But Now i wanted to use this same list along with the same filters and functions on different places.Right now all code is written in one single controller.

Now my question is that do i need to convert in a single directive or in service ?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you wanting? Use the filtered data somewhere else? Or use the same filtering UI somewhere else? Question is not clear and also no code is provided as per [mcve]

Comment: i wanted to use same filtering UI on different places

Comment: So if the only difference would be the array data being filtered simplest would be create a directive that takes in data from attribute to pass to directive scope and put all the business logic in directive ( or service injected in directive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is that do i need to convert in a single directive or in service

Either choice is fine. I would create a single directive (for use in html) that uses a single service (to control the directive logic).

Comment: I have created single directive and place all logic in service to control directive . Now code is manageable and can be use any where. thanks !